# Copy files to docker image after build

Tags: shell, file, docker, copy

I do have an already build docker image and wan't to add files to it AFTER the build was done. Is there a way to add files without rebuilding it (or maybe to add it and save it with an new tag)? I did find `docker cp` but if I understand that right it does only work in running containers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) but if I understand that right it does only work in running containers

Still, that might work considering you can then commit a container into a new image.
See [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/).

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Comment: Ah didn't see that. I will take a look at it to check if that is what I wanted to do.